# How did the pattern of church today come to be?

Tags: church-history

How did we come up with the way church services are done. Worship, sermon, communion etc. I want to know the roots. What scriptures tell us to do it like this.

Comment: Depends on who you mean by we. Various Christian traditions worship in different ways. Which worship style did you have in mind?

Comment: Here are a couple of more specific versions of your question that are already on the site: [When and why did Protestantism begin moving away from liturgy?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42762/when-and-why-did-protestantism-begin-moving-away-from-liturgy?rq=1) & [When did the one-way monologue sermon first become a normal feature of church assemblies?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11586/when-did-the-one-way-monologue-sermon-first-become-a-normal-feature-of-church-as) Perhaps you could edit yours to focus on something that these don't already cover?

Comment: I might also recommend a time frame.  How the churches by AD150 came to be is a much different discussion than how the churches by AD 1925 came to be.  By limiting your scope this will become an answerable question.  Thanks!